# How to change drawable of actionbar overflow menu when it's opened

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable, statelistdrawable

I want to change drawable of actionbar overflow item until menu is opened. When I select an option (and so menu return closed) I want switch back to default drawable.

I try different "state_X" but no one works. Can you help me please?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/new_icon_action_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/new_icon_action_2" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Can u explain in detail? I can't get u...

Comment: When I tap on overflow menu of actionbar (with 3 vertical squares) I want to change icon until menu is visible or until I select an option. I tried to use state_window_focused but it's not a perfect result.

Comment: Do you want Ur icons that stay on action bar to change when u click on overflow menu (the three dots)?

Comment: No, I want that overflow menu's icon remain changed until menu is opened.